# the fewest number of parameters to define a 2D line

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to define any arbitrary line with (0,0) as origin in XY plane, **only** by a positive angle from X axis,such that the angle is a real number and, is between 0 and 360 degree?
If yes, could you please provide the equation?If no, please disprove it.

The angle can be limited from 90 to 270 degree, as the other part is it's mere continuation.

Comment: how would you describe a line not through the origin?

Comment: The equation $r=r(\theta)$ works only if every ray issued from the origin intersects the curve only once. For a more general curve one must resort to a parametric equation with parameter different from $\theta$.

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry, thanks for pointing out the hole in my question. Let me redefine the question:Is it possible to define any arbitrary line with (0,0) as origin in XY plane, only by a positive angle from X axis,such that the angle is a real number and, is between 0 and 360 degree? If yes, could you please provide the equation?If no, please disprove it.

Comment: @Aretino, do you mean (θ) is 1?

Comment: Sorry: I hadn't understood it was a *straight* line.

Comment: @Aretino, it's k. Generally when we say line we mean a straight line with a constant rate of change.

Comment: The equation for a line through origin is $ax+by=0$ where $(a,b)$ is the normal to the line. By using an angle you get this normal to be $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @skyking, I think you are close, but I need equation of the line with a single parameter θ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal to the line would be $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ and the equation for a line with given normal $(a, b)$ is $ax + by = c$ (where $c$ is a suitably chosen constant). Since the line is to pass origin you have $a0+b0+c=c=0$. So the equation would be:

$y\cos\theta - x\sin\theta = 0$

or

$y\cos\theta = x\sin\theta$

Note that since $\theta$ could be fx $\pi/2$ (a vertical line) you can't in general have an expression of the form $y = kx+m$, but for those angles it works out it would be:

$y = x\tan\theta$

Comment: Thanks, @skyking. But is there anyway that we combine both x and θ here, to be expressed in a new novel form?

Comment: Here x is a variable and θ is a parameter; both are dynamically changing. Can both of these dynamic elements be merged together to form a single dynamic element?

Comment: expecting your valuable help still.

Comment: @JohnyRoyan I'm not sure what you're trying to say. $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of the points on the line, while $\theta$ is a parameter for the line, $\theta$ is the same for the whole line while $x$ and $y$ differs along the line.

Comment: in other words, can θ be irrational at any arbitrary point (x,y)?

Comment: @JohnyRoyan Yes, $\theta$ can be irrational, but it's the same for the whole line. Fx if you want the angle to be $\pi/6$ the equation of the line is $y\cos(\pi/6) = x \sin(\pi/6)$.

Comment: perfect reasoning